# Looping for matrix in R

Tags: r

I am developing a program for location allocation problem using p-median. Appreciated if anyone could help me to solve the problem I have in the program.

I have three matrices as below: 
AA=

```
    [,1] [,2]  [,3]  
[1,]  5.50 3.28 14.20  
[2,]  12.40 2.02  7.22 
[3,]  7.63 6.47  3.48
```

pop=

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1402  974 1052
```

cap1=

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 4050 780 130


    diss <- apply(AA,1,sort)
    ran <- apply(AA,1,rank)
    ordd <- apply(ran,2,order)

    prone <- function (pop,diss,ordd)
    {
      if (pop <= cap1[ordd])
      {a1<-diss* pop}
      else if (pop > cap1[ordd])
     {a1<-(cap1[ordd]* diss) + ((pop-cap1[ordd])* diss[,i+1])}
```

The program is supposed to take the second smallest `diss` value at `diss[,i+1]`, but it takes the smallest value of `diss` for the whole looping.

```
     else if (pop-cap1[ordd]>cap1[ordd[i+1])
     {a2<-a1+(cap1[ordd[i+1]])*diss[,i+2]} 

# the looping will continue untill comply the below condition

    else (pop<=cap1[ordd[i+2]]
    }

    prone1 <- function (pop,diss,ordd)
    {
      for(i in 1:ncol(pop))
      {
        a2=prone(pop[,i],diss[,i][1],ordd[,i][1])
        if (i==1) 
        {a3<-a2}
        else if (i!=1) {a3<-rbind(a3,a2) 
        }
      }
      print(a3) 
    }
    prone1(pop,diss,ordd)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?